# How to delete a similar fragment on several HTML files?

Tags: html, regex, sed

I'm converting a website to a PDF, but there are images in there and along all of them there is a text that when clicked gets you to image itself.

I think this would be the code responsible for showing that text, since I deleted it in one of the files and the text and link is not shown anymore.

```
<div class="v1"><a target="_self" href="images/graphics/1.jpg">[View full size image]</a></div>
```

The problem is that there are about 200 more HTML documents containing this similar text, only changing `href`.

Would there be any easy way to get rid of all this without having to go one by one? Maybe a regular expression for `sed`?

Comment: are u using any IDE ????

Comment: If you want to parse HTML, use a [HTML Parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: I'm not using any IDE, I have a website I wanted to turn into PDF; I actually don't know much about web programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, regular expressions are likely the easiest solution here. If it's simply a question of removing this line from all your files then I'd just open them up in an editor ([Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com) does this well) and perform a regex search and replace. The following search pattern will likely work:

`<div class=\"v1\"><a target=\"_self\" href=\"[^"]+\">\[View full size image\]</a></div>`

Comment: Thank you for the regular expression, I changed it a bit to work with `sed` but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If the expression is always on one line and the only difference is in `href`, `sed` is a possible solution:

```
sed -e 's,<div class="v1"><a target="_self" href="[^"]*">\[View full size image\]</a></div>,,'
```

I used an alternative separator `,` so `/` does not have to be escaped in closing tags. The brackets in the links's text need to be escaped, though.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I marked as accepted the other one because it was the one I read and used; but this one is as valid as the other one.